# MVVMCross - Broadcasting a message works List<string> but not for List<T>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am binding the button's background image of my page to List elements. When those images are changed on other pages I use events to update the previous pages. This works fine when the list is of type string but when the list is of type say class T, it doesn't work.

View:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
set.Bind(Photo1Button).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand).WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), 1).OneWay();
            set.Bind(Photo2Button).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand).WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), 2).OneWay();
            set.Bind(Photo3Button).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand).WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), 3).OneWay();
            set.Bind(Photo4Button).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand).WithConversion(new MvxCommandParameterValueConverter(), 4).OneWay();

}

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{

base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
ViewModel.ReloadViewCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

ViewModel

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger mvxMessenger;
        #pragma warning disable CS0414
        private MvxSubscriptionToken onUserImageUpdate;
        #pragma warning restore CS0414

        private List<string> _userImages;
        public List<string> UserImages
        {
            get { return _userImages; }
            set
            {
                _userImages = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserImages);
            }
        }
public ICommand ReloadViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(() =>
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserImages);
                });

            }

        }
public ViewModel()
        {
            onUserImageUpdate = mvxMessenger.SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread<UserPhotoNotification>(OnUserImageUpdate);
        }

void OnUserImageUpdate(UserPhotoNotification message)
        {
            UserImages = message.Images;
        }
```

It all works fine when the list 'UserImage' is of type string. If I change the UserImage to to be of type T i.e.,

```
private List<abc> _userImages;
        public List<abc> UserImages
        {
            get { return _userImages; }
            set
            {
                _userImages = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserImages);
            }
        }
```

Then even though the changes can be seen through the debugger those changes are not updated on the screen.

Comment: I don't see any events in the code you have provided. It is unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: I meant broadcasting a message not events.

Comment: Am i missing anything?

Comment: I don't see where you are publishing any messages.

Comment: I only posted the subscribing code as the issue is, ones the message is subscribed it is not updating the UI with the I use list<T> but works well for List<string>.

Do you want publishing code too ?